# Determine if full text index population is paused

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am looking for a way to call the following only if the fulltext index status is paused but I can't seem to find the query I need to get the population status of a specific table

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.my_table RESUME POPULATION
```

I have several indexes in the one fulltext catalog so I cannot rely on `sys.fulltext_catalogs`. I have checked `sys.fulltext_indexes` and the two indexes - one running and one paused - appear identical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the catalogue property function...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190370.aspx

For example:

```
SELECT
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'PopulateStatus') AS [PopulateStatus]
FROM 
    sys.fulltext_catalogs AS cat
```

A status of '2' is paused.

Comment: > "I have several indexes in the one fulltext catalog so I cannot rely on `sys.fulltext_catalogs`"